# Multiple personal blogs merged in one

Tags: blogging

In my team we would like to have a single blog that merges all the posts that each individual has in its own blog (hosted in different blogging platforms that publish RSS/ATOM feeds). Is there any web platform that does this or my only option is to code my own?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems like WordPress MU might do something like this, but I'm not 100% sure of that. You might look into it.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel. After reading Wordpress MU it seems like this platform requires that you host all blogs in your own platform. I'm looking for a much simple solution that merges multiple RSS feeds into one blog.

Comment: *> After reading Wordpress MU it seems like this platform requires that you host all blogs in your own platform.*   If you asking asking about a hosted platform, then it is off-topic here and should be migrated to Webapps.

Answer (score 1):

From all of my searching, and that is the past hour. I can find no solution for you other then hosting one yourself. I found plenty of wordpress plugins that do just this but no wordpress hosts that allow the plugin.

But there is hope. Depending on the other people, blog.com allows atom posting. Which means you can use a desktop client that uses the atom protocol to post entries. Which if used in conjunction with their other blog would post on both sites simultaneously.

The only other option I see is email posting. Which most sites out there allow as well. So you and your fellow bloggers could post via email to multiple blogs at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're all using the same blog engine then you shoulld be able to export the posts and then import them back into a single instance of a blog.

For example, you could take 4 WordPress blogs, export the posts from MySQL and then turn back around and import all four sets of posts back into a single WordPress blog.

Now if you have different blog engines for your team, then you are going to have to manually massage the posts to make them work.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was looking for a solution that wouldn't force me to code. With code we can do anything... I know... but I imagine that it could be possible to merge multiple RSS feeds (from different blog platforms) into a single blog platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the feeds with [Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_%28software%29).

Comment: That would require to setup my own server with the Planet platform... right? We are just looking for an existing web site that offers custom RSS merging already.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/). :)

> SimplePie is a very fast and easy-to-use feed parser, written in PHP,
>   that puts the 'simple' back into 'really simple syndication'. Flexible
>   enough to suit beginners and veterans alike, SimplePie is focused on
>   speed, ease of use, compatibility and standards compliance.

Comment: Thanks bpartch. I didn't know about this platform but I believe it requires to setup our own web server and we are just looking for an existing solution that would allow us to merge different blogs into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) or something similar to combine the RSS feeds and then use some sort of service to automatically post items from that feed to a blog. It seems you might be able to hack up some sort of solution going this route without needing to self host.